# Set C++11 in Eclipse CDT Luna

Tags: c++11, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-luna

I'm using Eclipse Luna, working on a big project, I got a new part of it, and it has something written in C++11

I tried to add to Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > GCC C++ Compiler > Miscellaneous > Other Flags: -std=c++11

When I try to build project, I get error:
unrecognized option '-std=c++11'

Comment: What version of GCC are you using?  Pre version 4.7 the option was -std=c++0x.

Comment: I'm using Mingw GCC++ 4.8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on eclipse Documentation:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#CDT_does_not_recognize_C.2B.2B11_features

Since Eclipse Luna, it cant be set with flags, but rather use Dialect option and also include it in Configure workspace settings